# Why won't my switch statement generate the correct results?

Tags: php, get, switch-statement, conditional-statements, default-value

I am using a condition and a switch to determine some default values for a few variables, but I am not getting the results that I expect.

When the link `<a href="index.php?post=myFile"></a>` is clicked, I expect to execute the first case in the switch, but the desired variables are not overwritten.

This is my code that are into my index.php:

```
$titulo = '';
$keywords = '';
$descricao = '';
$post = empty($_GET['post']) ? '' : $_GET['post'];
$pagina = empty($_GET['p']) ? 'home' : $_GET['p'];

if (empty($post)) {
    switch ($pagina):
    case 'posts/myFile':
        $titulo = 'this variable doesnot change the value on this file';
        $keywords = 'this variable doesnot change the value on this file';
        $descricao = 'this variable doesnot change the value on this file';
        break;
    case 'privacidade':
        $titulo = 'Privacidade ';
        break;
    case 'ultimasnoticias':
        $titulo = 'Ultimas Noticias';
        break;
    default:
        $titulo = 'Home';
        $pagina = 'home';
    endswitch;
} else {
    $titulo = 'Post';
}
```

My current results are:

```
$_GET["post"] = "myFile";
$titulo = "Post";
$keywords = "";
$descricao = "";
$pagina = "home";
```

My desired results are:

```
$_GET["post"] = "myFile";
$titulo = 'this variable doesnot change the value on this file';
$keywords = 'this variable doesnot change the value on this file';
$descricao = 'this variable doesnot change the value on this file';
$pagina = "home";
```

Why am I not able to update the variables using the first case statement?

Edit:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6wz5.jpg)

This is the code that are into my index.php to the `nav bar`:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="?p=home">Início</a></li>
     <li><a href="?p=ultimasnoticias">Últimas Notícias</a>
     <li><a href="?p=contato">Contato</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Double Check $post value. is it coming empty or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load `index.php?post=myFile`, you are generating the following element in the `$_GET` superglobal array:

```
$_GET = array ("post" => "myFile");
```

Then `$post = empty($_GET['post']) ? '' : $_GET['post'];` declares `$post = "myFile"`.

This means that `if (empty($post)) {` evaluates to `false` (because it is not empty, it is `myFile`) and the `switch-case` block is ignored.

The `else` condition is executed. `$titulo = 'Post';`

---

Now, if you want the switch-case block to be executed, you must:

- Change `if (empty($post)) {` to `if (!empty($post)) {`.

---

As for future trouble you may have within the switch-case block, make sure that you are identically matching the value for `$pagina` when writing each case.  If you aren't sure about what values you are working with or what is being executed, just add echoes in each case to clarify.

I say this because `posts/myFile` is not the same string as `myFile`.

---

After more discussion about other hyperlinks, I'll recommend changing the default value for `$pagina` and extending the `if` logic to be more inclusive.

```
$pagina = empty($_GET['p']) ? '' : $_GET['p'];         // I changed 'home' to ''

if ($post != '' || ($post == '' && $pagina != '')) {   // I changed the logic
```